# How add pages to panoramaItem?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot, controltemplate, panorama-control

I want to have panorama control (or pivot ) that each PanoramaItem will be some 
 MyPage.xaml. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create each page as a user control (MyPage.xaml)
2. In your panorama or pivot control, add a pivotitem or panormaitem
3. Replace the default grid child of each pivotItem or PanoramaItem with an instance of the page created in step 1.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I am just new in wp7. Can you tell me good tutorial,book or smth esle where is good written about panorama and pivot controls.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx

Comment: @ Rich Hopkins  , Thnaks, I knew about this book

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader

We've used it to set up a listbox like so:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
lb.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load("XAML as a string here");
```

Not exactly what you want, but should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I have different pages, and I want to put them in panorama. And change page when page is scrolled. How can I do that? And do you know good tutorial about panorama control ?